# Ruby on Rails simple_form label: false still displays label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm getting started with Ruby on Rails and simple_form however I can't figure out how to disable the input label. I've tried `label: false` however when I do this it simply uses the field name as the label. How can I completely turn the label off for this field? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want the label?

Comment: When it displays the label it messes up some other formatting that is more important to what I'm doing then using the label provided by simple_form.

Answer (score -1):

Never used simple_form, but what about:

```
label: ""
```

Comment: This just defaults to the column name on the db